# Setting onClicklistener() doesn't work in a fragment

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

Button `onClick` doesn't work in a `fragment`. What happens? 
The id and `onClickListener` function has the right syntax. I don't know what is happening.

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    Button btn;
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    btn = (Button)vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View vista) {
            //cargarWebService();
            //name.setText("");
            //email.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Se ah registrado exitosamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
```

to

```
 return vista;
```

let me know if this work or not

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to inflate the view again when returning it, simply inflate it once at the beginner of the method and then return the view at the end of the method.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

return view;
```